# Gazebo custom model structure

Tags: gazebo, sdformat, gazebo-11

How can I organize the model structure when using gazebo?
I have a world file which include a robot with

```
        <model name='robot'>
            <pose frame=''> 0 0 0.94 0 -0 -1.57</pose>
            <include>
                <uri>robot</uri>
            </include>
        </model>
```

For the robot, I want to define a wheel that is used multiple times for the robot. I tried to include it as

```
        <link name='left_wheel_body'>
            <pose>0. 0. 0. 3.14159 0. 3.14159</pose>
            <include>
                <uri>wheel</uri>
            </include>
        </link>
        <joint name='left_wheel_joint' type='revolute'>
            <child>left_wheel_body</child>
            <parent>base_body</parent>
...
```

and wheel model.sdf looks like

```
<sdf version='1.7'>
    <model name='wheel'>
        <link name='wheel_body'>
            <inertial>
                <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
                <mass>0.5</mass>
            </inertial>
            <visual name='wheel_body_visual'>
                <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder>
                        <length>0.01</length>
                        <radius>0.02</radius>
                    </cylinder>
                </geometry>
            </visual>
        </link>
    </model>
</sdf>
```

The structure of the file is defined as

```
├─ robot
│  ├─ model.sdf   
│  └─ model.config
│
├─ wheel
│  ├─ model.sdf   
│  └─ model.config
│
└─ simple_world.world
```

However it kept saying that `Error: Non-unique names detected in type model in` Does anyone know how to fix this?
Also I am including the absolute path to include wheel and robot into world file. But I is there a way to include relative path to include those model into the world / sdf file?

Thank you

Comment: I am only including wheel.sdf once currently to test it. But it still complain about non-unique name

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: If one of these answers helped you, please click the checkmark to turn it green.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a name tag in your include to override the name in the included sdf, see the [SDFormat specification](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.11&elem=world#include_name).

For the relative path, use `<uri>model://file.sdf</uri>` and set the environment variable

- `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` for Gazebo Classic,
- `IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` for Ignition Gazebo <= 7, or
- `GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH` for Gazebo Sim >= 7.

See also [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/gazebosim/sdformat/issues/1234).

Answer (score 0):

1. In sdf, if you `<include>` a model more than once at the same level, you must also provide a unique `<name>` tag for it. This is used to uniquely name that instance of the object.
2. Also, I think your `<uri>` tag should look like `<uri>model://wheel</uri>`
3. I doubt you can reference model 'robot' from inside `<model name='robot'>`
4. According to the sdf specification, `<include>` is not a valid child of tag `<link>`.